# how to use grep capital whole first word

Tags: grep

I have a data about customer, it's like

```
custimer, age , street, work
Tom,45,street1,manager
Michel,23,street4,manager

Bob,23,street5,manager
```

what I need do is clean the blank lines and make customer name in capital letters.
I know the clean code should be

```
grep '\S' filename
```

but how can I capital name?

Comment: Please add your desired output (no description, no images, no links) for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: You probably want `grep '^[[:upper:]]' filename`

Answer (score 0):

Whole first word, not just first letter?  [awk](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html) would be a good one for that, it handles CSV's well.

specify input Field-seperator as a comma `-F,`
set Output Field Seperator to a comma `BEGIN { OFS="," }`
skip whitespaces `/\S/`
change first column to capitals `$1 = toupper($1)`
then print the entire edited line `print $0`

```
awk -F, 'BEGIN { OFS="," } /\S/ { $1 = toupper($1) ; print $0 }' filename > newfilename
```

---

You can specify both the Field Seperator and Output Field Seperator in that BEGIN block, if you prefer.

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS="," ; OFS="," } /\S/ { $1 = toupper($1) ; print $0 }' filename > newfilename
```